# What is wrong with my HyperlinkButton?

Tags: c#, xaml, silverlight, windows-phone-7, hyperlink

I was making my list more nice by changing my HyperlinkButton style and then my app just stopped working.. The debugger shows nothing to me.

My xaml code:

```
<ListBox Name="Listing" ItemsSource="{Binding Coletores,Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>

                            <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                                <HyperlinkButton NavigateUri="/OcorrenciasPage.xaml" Name="hlbColetor" Click="hlbColetor_Click">
                                    <HyperlinkButton.Content>
                                        <StackPanel>
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Nome}" FontSize="42"/>
                                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                                                <TextBlock FontSize="24" FontWeight="Light">
                                                    <Run Text="x:"/>
                                                    <Run Text="{Binding Latitude}"/>
                                                </TextBlock>
                                                <TextBlock FontSize="24" FontWeight="Light" Margin="20,0,0,0">
                                                    <Run Text="y:"/>
                                                    <Run Text="{Binding Longitude}"/>
                                                </TextBlock>
                                            </StackPanel>
                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </HyperlinkButton.Content>
                                </HyperlinkButton>
                                <Line Width="*" Stroke="Gray" StrokeThickness="4"/> 
                            </StackPanel>

                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
```

And the code behind:

```
public ColetoresPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            db = new AppDataContext();

            DataContext = this;      
        }

        private ObservableCollection<Coletor> _coletor;
        public ObservableCollection<Coletor> Coletores
        {
            get { return _coletor; }
            set
            {
                _coletor = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Coletores");
            }
        }

        protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

            Coletores = new ObservableCollection<Coletor>(PessoaAux.coletores);
        }

        private void hlbColetor_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Button btn = sender as Button;
            if (btn != null)
            {
                Coletor coletor = btn.DataContext as Coletor;
                ColetorAux.id = coletor.Id;
                ColetorAux.nome = coletor.Nome;
                ColetorAux.longitude = coletor.Longitude;
                ColetorAux.latitude = coletor.Latitude;
                ColetorAux.pessoa = coletor.Pessoa;
            }
        }
```

I don't know what is wrong, my code was running normal before some edits but I don't know what edit I done is bugging my code

Comment: What do you mean stopped working? Are you looking at the output window for binding errors?

Comment: When I navigate to this page the debugger crashes but there is nothing in the error window..

Comment: And if you remove everything and keep as usual, does it work?

Comment: @GustavoMendonça Is there anything in the output window?

Comment: @jfin3204 `A first chance exception of type 'MS.Internal.WrappedException' occurred in System.Windows.dll` this is in the output window.

Comment: @JuanPabloGarciaCoello I don't know because I don't remember what exactly I changed.

Comment: @GustavoMendonça a couple of things to try.  If you are using Content frames try setting the target property of the hyperlink.  Also try using the application_unhandledException event in the App.xaml.cs file and setting a breakpoint to catch whatever exception is causing the app to crash